# Como passo uma variável para dentro de um frame?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá, tudo bem? Eu queria passar uma variável que contém um resultado para dentro de um frame que contém um gráfico e então o gráfico usaria essa esse valor e plotaria no gráfico.

Eu estou programando em Ionic 3, HTML, JavaScript e SCSS.

Como faço para pegar a variável que está no JavaScript e jogar dentro do frame que está carregando no HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Essa pergunta já existe no SO em inglês, mas pra facilitar sua compreensão vou dar uma traduzida

Na página onde o iframe aparecerá:

```
function myFunction(){
$('#meuIframe').attr('src', "meuIframe.html?param1=value1&param2=value2"); 
}
```

Dentro do seu iframe:

```
function getParamValue(paramName) {
    var url = window.location.search.substring(1); // Pega as variaveis na url
    var qArray = url.split('&'); // pega os pares de chave e valores
    for (var i = 0; i < qArray.length; i++) {
        var pArr = qArray[i].split('='); // Separa a Chave do Valor
        if (pArr[0] == paramName) 
            return pArr[1]; // Retorna o Valor
    }
}
```

Se você quiser pegar um parâmetro específico use:

```
var param1 = getParamValue('param1');
```

[Link do post Original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295870/how-to-pass-parameters-through-iframe-from-parent-html/28296334)

Créditos: [Ozgur Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4429070/ozgur-bar)

Comment: var param1 = getParamValue('param1'); eu devo colocar no js e especificar a variavel que eu queira mandar?   e essa:: function myFunction(){
$('#meuIframe').attr('src', "meuIframe.html?param1=value1&param2=value2"); 
}    eu jogo dentro do html?